# iOS 7 status bar issue

Tags: ios

I am able to resolve my status bar issue by using following code.

```
if(!SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"7.0")){
    // This property is required for iOS 7+ version so that view did not hide under the navigation bar.
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
}
```

Right now I am adding this code in viewDidload method. I have many screen in Storyboard.
 Do I need to add these line in every single viewController viewDidLoad method or Is there any other way to fix this issue, so that I do not need to update each single view controller code.

Comment: With 80 screens in a storyboard, I don't want to know the load time of opening that storyboard in Xcode...

Answer (score 3):

You could subclass UIViewController and put your code in the subclass' `viewDidLoad` method (don't forget to call `[super viewDidLoad]`).  Then each view controller class in your storyboard could inherit from the subclass (don't forget to call `[super viewDidLoad]`).